# RatingBar - Toggle or unrate

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

**Backdrop:**
We are using the standard Android RatingBar with 5 stars. We allow users to rate using this RatingBar from 1 to 5. The default values we show is zero that is not rated.

**Problem:**
The user currently is not able to unrate or set the rating back to zero after they click on the Rating Bar even once. They can only make it the least value which is 1. This cannot be done even in the code as the onRatingChange event is not called if you click on the same rating more than once.

Any thoughts on how to overcome this and is it possible? Will creating a new subclass with RatingBar help in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
The question does not have any code as it does not pertain to problems in code. This is a question on functionality and limitations of RatingBar.

Comment: Why was this down voted? Care to explain?

Comment: Add a button to remove rating

Comment: @PravinCGL I suppose its because you have provided the problem description but not the code which may be the suspect. It's not my downvote by the way. ;-)

Comment: I would be surprised if that was the case as the question does not pertain to code but functionality of Android Rating Bar.

Comment: @BinoyBabu: Yes that is a solution but I want to know if this is a limitation of Rating Bar.

Comment: How about sliding left in the rating bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To unrate an Android `RatingBar`, the user have to slide to the left end of the `RatingBar`. Just clicking on the last star will not unrate.

Comment: Yep this works. Have they mentioned this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: No, I just learned about this today. Looked at the source to see if there was the functionality. Anyway, I don't think many users are gonna find this. You may want to add some kind of hint or button.

Comment: I guess everyone assumes that RatingBar is for clicking not sliding.